# Can I send sales emails to different addresses based on cart contents?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, email

The client wants to have all sales emails CC’d to a second address if a certain category of product is in the cart. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box. This can be best done by creating an extension that observes an event like `sales_order_place_after`, checks the order items for a certain type of product and then sends the email some what like the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` class `sendNewOrderEmail` method.

So without having tested it here is what the observer class should look like

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{

   public function sendCC(Varien_Observer_Event $observer)
   {
      $_order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

      $has_trigger = false;
      foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $_item)
      {
         if ([your check for product here]) $has_trigger = true;
      }

      if (!$has_trigger) return $this;

      $store_id = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
      $email_recipient_name = '[ name of 3th party recipient ]';
      $email_recipient_email = '[ email of 3th party recipient ]';

      try {
         $paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($this->getPayment())
           ->setIsSecureMode(true);
         $paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($store_id);
         $paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
      } catch (Exception $exception) {
         throw $exception;
      }

      $template_id = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $store_id);

      $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');

      $email_info = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
      $email_info->addTo($email_recipient_email, $email_recipient_name);
      $mailer->addEmailInfo($email_info);

      $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $store_id));
      $mailer->setStoreId($store_id);
      $mailer->setTemplateId($template_id);
      $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
         'order'        => $_order,
         'billing'      => $_order->getBillingAddress(),
         'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
      ));

      return $this;
   }
}
```

Or optionally, I've used [this extension](http://www.xtento.com/magento-extensions/magento-order-export-module.html) before which worked pretty well but is somewhat expensive. It will allow you to export orders in different ways on different observers

Comment: Thanks! I'm very new to magento, so I'm not going to try to implement that code, but the extension looks like it will suit my needs well. Cheers